# How to connect openvpn on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: 16.04, openvpn

I have my usual `openvpn` config files that I use on a `Windows` OS:

```
myuser.crt
myuser.key
ca.crt
key.txt
open_short.bat.x
openvpn
openvpn.ovpn
openvpn-status.log
README.txt
```

I run (as `root`):

> openvpn --config /etc/local/openvpn/openvpn.ovpn

However, it prompts me to

> Enter Auth Username:

I'm not sure how to proceed as it doesn't behave that way in Windows, where I run it via `openvpn-gui` but the same config files.

Answer (score 0):

the auth ussername is "vpnbook" and you can find the password on https://www.vpnbook.com/

Comment: I can't find where on that site to find the passwd

Comment: once you open the site click on PPTP you will find the auth username and password there.

Comment: Username: vpnbook
Password: d4bmcut "the password will change every two days, so check for password regularly.

Comment: I hope that's just one time upon setup and not every time...

Comment: Do I have to enter those credentials every time?

Comment: yes you have to enter it everytime as the password changes.

Comment: Is there a way to circumvent that step, like Windows does?

Comment: @Sazzy how can you be sure that they're using vpnbook?